# Where does "has" come from in "this.has" expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I was reading `Nats-Jetstream` [documentation](https://github.com/uber-archive/jetstream) that I encountered the following code:

```
var createModel = require('jetstream').model;

var Shape = createModel('Shape', function() {
    this.has('x', Number);
    this.has('y', Number);
    this.has('width', Number);
    this.has('height', Number);
    this.has('type', Number);
});
```

I am not sure what does `this.has` mean? Where does the `has` come from? How does this code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of the library is described [in the docs](https://github.com/uber-archive/jetstream/blob/master/docs/overview.md). It has:

```
type JetStream : {
    model: (name: String, fn: ModelDefiner) => Model,
```

So the callback is a ModelDefiner, which is defined here:

```
type ModelDefiner : (this: Model) => void
```

So `this` is a `Model`, which is defined here:

```
type ModelObject : {
    has: (propertyName: String, PropertyType) => void,
    setScope: (scope: Scope, Callback<Error, void>) => void,
    getValues: () => Object,
    getAddSyncFragment: () => SyncFragment<"add">
}

-- A Model instance inherits from ModelObject.
type Model : ModelObject & {
    typeName: String,
    uuid: ObjectUUID,
    scope: Scope | null
}
```

As you can see above, a Model extends a ModelObject, and a ModelObject has a `has` method.

If you're curious how you would write code that could do this yourself, all you really need is to create an object with a `has` method, and [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the callback with it.

```js
class Model {
  has(str, type) {
    console.log('has called with', str, type);
  };
}
const createModel = (str, callback) => {
  const model = new Model();
  callback.call(model);
};

var Shape = createModel('Shape', function() {
    this.has('x', Number);
    this.has('y', Number);
    this.has('width', Number);
    this.has('height', Number);
    this.has('type', Number);
});
```

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: The code snippet is just JavaScript. If you're asking about the types, I don't know if it's a particular language - it's in a `.md` file, after all - though it looks pretty similar to TypeScript

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still can't understand the `:`s and expressions before them. I asked the same question in the comments of the other answer.

Comment: What comes before the colon is the identifier/argument/property name. What comes after the colon is the type of that identifier/argument/property.

Answer (score 1):

When curious, it's always good to look at the source, which they've made available. First thing to check since this is a node project would be the package.json -- main is "index". All the exports are going to be defined in libs/index.js.

Looking at libs/index.js line 52, we see where model is defined as an export -- it's a function where you pass in a name and definition that get passed to ModelObject.model; if you scroll back up, you can see that that's included from libs/model_object.js.

Going over to libs/model_object, you can see what the passed definitions field (the lambda function you see in the example code) is used for: `definitions.call(typeClass)`. `typeClass` is created earlier in the function. If you're unfamiliar with what call does, it lets a function be executed in another object -- the `this` you see in the passed function is going to refer to the `typeClass` object. Inside of libs/model_object.js, a has function is defined that adds ModelObjectProperties; `this.has` is being used to add properties to the ModelObject.

edit:  CertainPerformance's answer is probably more clear, refer to that.

Comment: Your answer was also great! But I still can't understand the syntax. For example `model: function(name, definition) { return ModelObject.model(name, definition); }` is kinda weird to me. I can't understand `model : ....` part. This is the first time I see (a word), then (colon), then *a function definition).

Comment: What do words before `:` do? It's like a label.

Comment: It's defining a map of named exports; model is the key, and the part after the semicolon is what you're getting. `require('jetstream')` gives you access to the module.exports, and then specifying `require('jetstream').model` means you're getting the export named `model` -- in this case it means that after running `var createModel = require('jetstream').model;`,  createModel is now referring to that function after the semicolon. Does that make sense?